# How to use other methods to realize `Differences`

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

I know the following method can get the desired result `{b-a,c-b,d-c,e-d}`:

```
Differences[{a, b, c, d, e}]
```

But I want to know more about how to do this.

```
MovingMap[Subtract, {a, b, c, d, e}, 1]
```

Please provide as many methods as possible.

Answer (score 10):

```
Rest @ # - Most @ # & @ {a, b, c, d, e}
#[[2 ;;]] - #[[;; -2]]& @ {a, b, c, d, e}
{1, -1}.Through @ {Rest, Most} @ {a, b, c, d, e}
Most[RotateLeft @ # - #]& @ {a, b, c, d, e}
ListConvolve[{1, -1}, {a, b, c, d, e}]
ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}, {a, b, c, d, e}]
MovingMap[#.{-1, 1} &, {a, b, c, d, e}, 1]
#2 - # & @@@ Subsequences[{a, b, c, d, e}, {2}]
Subsequences[{a, b, c, d, e}, {2}].{-1, 1}
#2 - # & @@@ Partition[{a, b, c, d, e}, 2, 1]
Partition[{a, b, c, d, e}, 2, 1].{-1, 1}
BlockMap[#.{-1, 1} &, {a, b, c, d, e}, 2, 1]
BlockMap[#2- # & @@ #&, {a, b, c, d, e}, 2, 1]
Partition[{a, b, c, d, e}, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, Minus @* Subtract]
ReplaceList[{w___, x_, y_, z___} :> y - x] @ {a, b, c, d, e}
SequenceCases[{a, b, c, d, e}, {a_, b_} :> b - a, Overlaps -> True]
Table[#[[i]] - #[[i - 1]], {i, 2, Length@#}] &@{a, b, c, d, e}
Function[x, Array[x[[# + 1]] - x[[#]] &, Length[x] - 1]] @ {a, b, c, d,  e}
{a, b, c, d, e}.SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, {4, 4}] -> -1, Band[{2, 1}, {5, 4}] -> 1}]
FoldPairList[{#2 - #1, #2} &, {a, b, c, d, e}] (* thanks: m_goldberg *)
Subtract @@@ Reverse /@ Partition[{a, b, c, d, e}, 2, 1] (* thanks: m_goldberg *)
```

Comment: If you are trying to be exhaustive, you might add `Subtract @@@ Reverse /@ Partition[{a, b, c, d, e}, 2, 1]`

Comment: People tend to forget about `FoldPairList`, but it works nicely for this problem. `FoldPairList[{#2 - #1, #2} &, {a, b, c, d, e}]`. You might want to add this one.

Comment: @m_goldberg, thank you for both suggestions. It didn't occur to me  `FoldPairList`  would be so straightforward.

Comment: Your 2nd example is my favorite. Beside being the most concise example, as an old Lisp programmer, I find it an a very intuitive representation of the operation being implemented.

Comment: @m_goldberg, it is also almost as efficient as `Differences` for numeric input.

Comment: Or  `Subtract @@@ -Partition[{a, b, c, d, e}, 2, 1] `

Answer (score 4):

```
MovingMap[Minus[Subtract @@ #] &, {a, b, c, d, e}, 1]
```

Comment: `MovingMap[-(Subtract @@ #) &, {a, b, c, d, e}, 1]` also do the job.

Answer (score 3):

First , we can see that

```
MovingMap[ # &, {a, b, c, d, e}, 1]
```

> {{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}, {d, e}}

So how to make `{a,b}` -> `b-a` ?

For example:

```
MovingMap[#[[2]] - #[[1]] &, {a, b, c, d, e}, 1]
```

Or

```
MovingMap[(Last@# - First@#) &, {a, b, c, d, e}, 1]
```

Or

```
MovingMap[Apply[#2 - #1 &], {a, b, c, d, e}, 1]
```

and so on.

Answer (score 3):

```
Most@NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[1,Range@Length@#,#,DifferenceOrder->1]&@{a,b,c,d,e}
```