# Please help me write my Formula

Tags: resolve

Suppose I have this nestlist t={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} How to calculate c=t(i)+t(i+1)

Comment: This can be archived in multiple ways: looking into the functions `ListConvolve`, `Part`+`Span`, `Table`+`Part`+`Lenght` might give you an idea. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html could also be a good place to start looking for a possible solution.

Comment: Closely related [coding frenzy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/231459/3066)

Answer (score 4):

```
t = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

Most[t] + Rest[t]

   (* or *)

t[[;;-2]] + t[[2;;]]
```

> {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}

> {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}

Answer (score 4):

A pretty general way of attacking problems like this that involve filtering data is to use ListConvolve. For this specific problem:

```
t = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

ListConvolve[{1, 1}, t]

{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be done very nicely by the function almost everybody forgets about.

```
t = Range[0, 10];
FoldPairList[{#1 + #2, #2}&, t]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
t = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

seq = Total /@ Partition[t, 2, 1]

(* {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19} *)
```

To find the general term of the sequence

```
c[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n]

(* -1 + 2 n *)
```

Verifying,

```
c /@ Range[Length[seq]] == seq

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively,

```
Clear[c, t]

eqns = {c[n] == t[n] + t[n + 1], t[n] == t[n - 1] + 1, t[1] == 0, t[2] == 1};

sol = RSolve[eqns, {c, t}, n][[1]]

(* {c -> Function[{n}, -1 + 2 n], t -> Function[{n}, -1 + n]} *)
```

Verifying the solutions,

```
eqns /. sol

(* {True, True, True, True} *)

c[n] /. sol

(* -1 + 2 n *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MovingMap[Total, Range[0, 10], 1]

(* Out: {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
t[[1 ;; Length@t - 1]] + t[[2 ;; Length@t]]
```

Or you can use `Drop` instead.

Comment: Actually what I first thought about was `sum(i+j for i, j in zip(t,t[1:]))` , and I wrote it in mma code.

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
t = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
Plus @@@ Partition[t, 2, 1]
```

Or

```
t = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
MovingMap[Total, t, 1]
```

> `{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}`

Comment: `t = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
Table[t[[i]] + t[[i + 1]], {i, 1, Length@t - 1}]` maybe suitable for beginner.